# Pause Python For Loop for a day

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

My situation is like this: I use the Selenium Webdriver to scrape a webpage, first it gets the total_page_items which is the easy part because the page has a number box at the top.

What I want to do know is interact with just 200 of these items each day.
Let's say for example the page has 5 million items, how would I go about clicking 200 of these items a day, possible saving the button state to a list, and then the next day continue with the next 200 items?
I know about the timing function and how to run the script daily at a certain time, but I don't know how to move from there. Is this a situation where I would use a nested loop?

Here is the for loop that I have so far, I hope it makes sense

```
    daily_items = 200
    counter = 0
    ButtonXpathList = [
          "//div[@id='content']/div/div/div[2]/div/div/ul/li[",
                               1,
                               "]/div/div[3]/button [contains(text(), 'Click')]"
     ]



    for i in range(0, daily_items):

        ButtonXpathList[1]  = ButtonXpathList[1] + (1) #Counts up the string
        ButtonXpathString = "".join(str(x) for x in ButtonXpathList)
        ButtonElement = WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, (ButtonXpathString))))
        action.move_to_element(ButtonElement)

        if "Click" in ButtonXpathString: # and ButtonElement.is_displayed():
            ButtonElement.click()
            counter += 1
            print counter, "New Buttons Clicked"
        else:
            driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", ButtonElement)
        time.sleep(2)

    if ButtonXpathList[1] == total_page_items:
        print "You're done here"
```

Comment: I wouldn't keep the script running and pause for a day. I would probably write the items to a file and then run a script each day that pulls 200 items from the file and does whatever. You do realize that if you have 5M items and do 200 a day that you are talking about 68.5 years to complete this task, right? :)

Comment: Thanks Jeff, I missed your post but I figured out this smarter approach as well. I'm now successfully writing and reading a textile, it works perfectly!  About the 68.5 years, I'm still young and not in a hurry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to use APScheduler. I have made something similar, a **scraper** that needed to run once every morning. APScheduler is simple to use:

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler    

scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()
scheduler.start()
scheduler.add_job(yout_routine, 'interval', days=1)
```

You can also use hour and minute interval:

```
scheduler.add_job(yout_routine, 'interval', hours=24)
```

docs: https://apscheduler.readthedocs.org/en/latest/